# How to achieve "lstItemXY" from "listItemArray"?

Tags: java, android, json

> I have an lstItemArry as shown below example.

```
  ArrayList lstItemArry= {id  productid  qty
                          1   175        1
                          2   175        1
                          3   182        1
                         }
```

> Logic Implemented

```
    for (int i = 0; i < lstItemArry.size(); i++) {

        PieDataChart json_data = lstItemArry.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < lstItemArry.size(); j++) {

            PieDataXYChart json_xy = new PieDataXYChart();

            if (json_data.getProduct_id() == lstItemArry.get(j).getProduct_id()) {
                json_xy.setProduct_id(
                        json_data.getProduct_id(
                                json_xy.setQuantity(json_data.getQuantity() + lstItemArry.get(j).getQuantity()
                                )
                        )
                );

                lstItemXY.add(json_xy);
            }
        }
    }

    //print all element
    for (PieDataXYChart element : lstItemXY) {
        System.out.println("Number = " + element);
    }
```

my OutPut received "lstItemXY":

```
 product_id 182  quantity 2
 product_id 175  quantity 2
 product_id 175  quantity 2   
 product_id 175  quantity 2
 product_id 175  quantity 2
```

But I wanted my "lstItemXY" to received like below:

```
 product_id 182  quantity 1
 product_id 175  quantity 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [groupingBy](https://dzone.com/articles/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-java-stream-api-grouping)...

Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::bitCount)) --> {1=[1, 2, 4], 2=[3, 5]}

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/ ""   2.2 Group by the name + Count or Sum the Qt ""

Answer (score 0):

```
   import java.math.BigDecimal;
     import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class Java8Examples3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //3 apple, 2 banana, others 1
        List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
                new Item("apple", 10, new BigDecimal("9.99")),
                new Item("banana", 20, new BigDecimal("19.99")),
                new Item("orang", 10, new BigDecimal("29.99")),
                new Item("watermelon", 10, new BigDecimal("29.99")),
                new Item("papaya", 20, new BigDecimal("9.99")),
                new Item("apple", 10, new BigDecimal("9.99")),
                new Item("banana", 10, new BigDecimal("19.99")),
                new Item("apple", 20, new BigDecimal("9.99"))
        );

        Map<String, Long> counting = items.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.counting()));

           System.out.print(counting);

        Map<String, Integer> sum = items.stream().collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Item::getQty)));

        System.out.print(sum);

      }
     }
```

Copy
output

```
//Group by + Count
    {
      papaya=1, banana=2, apple=3, orang=1, watermelon=1
    }

//Group by + Sum qty
    {
        papaya=20, banana=30, apple=40, orang=10, watermelon=10
     }
```

https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-collectors-groupingby-and-mapping-example/

Answer (score 0):

In Android when "Collectors" not support

```
  Map<String, List<PieDataChart>> map = new HashMap<String, List<PieDataChart>>();

                    for (PieDataChart student : lstItemArry) {
                        String key  = String.valueOf(student.getProduct_id());
                        if(map.containsKey(key)){
                            List<PieDataChart> list = map.get(key);
                            list.add(student);

                        }else{
                            List<PieDataChart> list = new ArrayList<PieDataChart>();
                            list.add(student);
                            map.put(key, list);
                        }

                    }




for (Map.Entry<String, List<PieDataChart>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                      //  System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " value : " + entry.getValue());

                       // for (int i=0 ; i< entry.getKey().length(); i++){
                        int sum = 0, value;
                            for (int j = 0; j < entry.getValue().size(); j++){

                                value = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(entry.getValue().get(j)));
                                //System.out.println(j+ "value = " + value);
                                sum += value;

                              //  System.out.println(j+"chgevalue = " + sum);
                            }
                   // }
                        System.out.println( "Key : " + entry.getKey() + "qty = " + sum);

                    }
```